# Need a simpler way to test many OR's in sql

Tags: mysql

In MySql I have a query like ...

```
select x,y,a,b,c,d,e from thetable where
a!= 0 OR b!= 0 OR c!=0 OR d!=0 OR e!=0
```

Any shorter way to write all those OR's ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `NOT IN (set of values comma separated)`

***Example***:

```
select * from thetable where 0 not in ( a, b, c, d );
```

If atleast a column has a `0` in a row, that row is omitted.

***Refer To***: [*MySQL: NOT IN ()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in)

---

***Update 1***:

> *Well this would eliminate any case where one of the them was zero. But I want to select is if any of them is not zero. So if 5 of them are 0 and one is something else, the answer should be true.*

May be you would need something similar to this:

```
select * from thetable where replace(concat(a,b,c,d,e,x,y),0,'') != '';
```

A working example is shown below:

```
create table t( a int, b int, c int );
insert into t values( 1,0,2 );
insert into t values( 2,5,4 );
insert into t values( 6,10,12 );
insert into t values( 0,3,8 );
insert into t values( 11,23,0 );
insert into t values( -1,6,-90 );
insert into t values( 0,0,0 );

mysql> select *, 
              concat(a,b,c) concatenated,
              replace(concat(a,b,c),0,'') replaced
       from t;
+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
| a    | b    | c    | concatenated | replaced |
+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
|    1 |    0 |    2 | 102          | 12       |
|    2 |    5 |    4 | 254          | 254      |
|    6 |   10 |   12 | 61012        | 6112     |
|    0 |    3 |    8 | 038          | 38       |
|   11 |   23 |    0 | 11230        | 1123     |
|   -1 |    6 |  -90 | -16-90       | -16-9    |
|    0 |    0 |    0 | 000          |          |
+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With a where condition, you can omit the last row as it has all the column values as zeros.

```
mysql>  select * from t where replace(concat(a,b,c),0,'') != '';
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |    2 |
|    2 |    5 |    4 |
|    6 |   10 |   12 |
|    0 |    3 |    8 |
|   11 |   23 |    0 |
|   -1 |    6 |  -90 |
+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Refer To***: [*MySQL Replace function*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Well this would eliminate any case where one of the them was zero.  But I want to select is if any of them is not zero.  So if 5 of them are 0 and one is something else, the answer should be true.